# AS3 Key down listener not working after returning to frame

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two frames, one labeled "mainFrame" and another labeled "secondFrame". When the program starts, the user clicks a button called start and that sends the user to "secondFrame". Once the user is on second frame, the KeyCode of whatever key they have pressed is traced and if the key pressed has the KeyCode of 68, the program returns to "mainFrame". This works fine, the problem is then when the user clicks the button again and returns to the "secondFrame" at which point the KeyCode does not trace. 
Here is the code on the mainFrame:

```
stop();
start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("secondFrame");
}
```

And the code on the secondFrame:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownCheck);

function keyDownCheck(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace(event.keyCode);
    if(event.keyCode == 68)
    {
        gotoAndStop("mainFrame");
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownCheck);
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupidly obvious that is preventing this from working, but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Whenever you `gotoAnd*` to another frame, the previous frame is destroyed and the destination frame is created anew. Check if `stage` is the same instance both times, also check if it isn't null while you add a listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer! Well, Zavr and Vesper actually said it xD The focus was being set out of the application, so stage.focus() = this worked. I don't know what I did that caused the errors when I tried it the first time but it works now xD Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this.setFocus() to the second frame's code.

Comment: Maybe `stage.setFocus()`?

Comment: maybe, i'm just used to flex. not sure what will this be in a flash app

Comment: Both ways just results in this error: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method setFocus through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage. Probably another stupid mistake I'm making xD

Answer (score -1):

Change second frame code to:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownCheck);
function keyDownCheck(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace(event.keyCode);
    if(event.keyCode == 68)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownCheck);
        gotoAndStop("mainFrame");        
    }
}
```

Comment: This might not work, because this is intended to solve the issue of traces appearing if not at second frame, OP has a reverse issue.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Strangely, I tried it a good ten times and one time it did work even on the second acessing of the secondFrame, and another didn't work even the first time I accessed the secondFrame... all the other times it did the same as before.